# whats the difference between html2canvas and rasterizehtml.js

Tags: html, canvas

Apparently there are solutions to capturing screenshot of a web page:

[Snapabug](http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/10/14/how-snapabug-works/) works by using an applet

[GrabzIt](http://grabz.it/api/javascript/) I guess this is done on the server side.

[Webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) is a command line tool, so not really part of the browser code.

There are probably other solutions that use ActiveX.

But I am interested in a Javascript only solution. From what I understand, both html2canvas and rasterizeHTML.js allow to convert html (in a web page) to an image. So, in what way is the implementation of html2canvas vs rasterizehtml.js different ? From what I understand both of them seem to use Canvas to generate the result. So in what way are they different? Which one is better ?

Answer (score 14):

The main difference is that Rasterize is a wrapper around [SVG foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) and html2canvas is essentially a reimplementation of browser HTML rendering from scratch. There are a lot of security headaches that Rasterize has to handle, but I think that its approach is better, as suggested by its being only 950 lines of code to html2canvas's 2400.

If the HTML you're rendering isn't very complex or doesn't need to be pixel-perfect, you may be able to skip Rasterize and use foreignObject directly, as described in [MDN: Drawing DOM objects into a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data   = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
               '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
                 '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
                   '<em>I</em> like <span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">cheese</span>' +
                 '</div>' +
               '</foreignObject>' +
             '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried html2canvas.js and rasterizeHTML.js for visualisation of a piece of html. Both have some issues, though. html2canvas.js can't get through with elements which have transformation (For example, text with css scale transform). As long as, I can't make rasterizeHTML.js to draw a canvas inside the canvas which displays the html.